# adding values to row and concatenating in dataframe while in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my dataframe i have a bit of gap between some rows in column hour. i am manually filling this gap by adding 1 to the columns "hour".when adding the values should not exceed the value which is there.There is a gap of 6 between the rows . for example when adding 1 each time until the value reaches 7 ( less than the value. i have created a temporary dataframe and made a copy extracting the index 0 and 1. i add 1 to each row in hour and then concatenate with the copy.i want this to go until it reaches 7 in a loop thats why i used while loop but using this i get an error " **The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()"**.Can someone help me fix this.Thankyou

```
hour,wage
1,15
2,17
8,20
9,25 
15,26
16,30
22,40
23,15
```

**import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.read_csv("text.txt")
print (df)

def hello(d):
   for i in range(len(d)-1):
        if (abs(d.iloc[i].hour - d.iloc[i+1].hour) > 5):
            compval = (abs(d.iloc[i].hour - d.iloc[i+1].hour))
            return compval
result = hello(df)

def tempor(data,value,gap):
    temp1 = df.iloc[0:2]
    dn = pd.DataFrame(temp1)
    temp2 = dn.copy()
    minus = temp2.iloc[-1]
    while minus + gap < value :
        temp1['hour'] = temp1['hour'].add(1).round(2)
        frames = [temp2,temp1]
        datafr = pd.concat(frames,ignore_index = True)
        print(datafr)


tempor(df,result,5)**
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the header of your while loop you add a value (gap) to a tuple (minus) and compare it to another value in line:

```py
while minus + gap < value :
    ...
```

You can't do it this way. The type of minus should be a value too, not list or tuple. You could fix that by getting one of the values from minus (hour, wage):

```py
while minus.hour + gap < value :
    ...
```

I am not totally sure what you want to achieve. With your data of text.txt the loop executes exactly zero times. Also when the while condition meets true you end up in an infinite loop, because none of the values within the while header (minus, gap, value) are altered when the loop executes.

Do you want to fill in the missing hours ?

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("text.txt")
print (df)

df2 = pd.DataFrame ( columns = ['hour', 'wage'], data = [
  [h, int(df[df['hour']==h].wage) if h in df.hour.values else 0]
  for h in range (0,24)
] )
print ( df2 )
```